# Colors of links are hard to distinguish from normal text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Yes, I used the exact same title as [another question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/colors-of-link-are-hard-to-distinguish-from-nornal-text) to show that I'm aware that it has been asked before. [However](http://www.suite101.com/content/grammatical-use-of-however-a56723), the previous question was for the "beta sketch" design. This is for the current [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) design.

Anyway, on both parent and meta, link colors somewhat blend in with the text. They're somewhat faded. They should be a little more prominent.

Here's a picture of a parent question:
[image: teh t3xtz]

Try to find the links in this meta question. It takes a second to scan if you haven't noticed them yet.

Comment: Good point... I can see the links easily enough, but for low-vision people it'd be pretty hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added underline for links in the question/comments/answers body. Should be more distinct now.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Now the only issue is the double-underline, but that's pointed out in [another thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/bugs-in-the-new-design).